# Polynomial Features and polynomial regression in sklearn

Tags: python, scikit-learn

I have two questions:

1. What is the output of `fit_transform` on a polynomial feature (what the numbers mean)? Correct me if I am wrong, but as far as I understood this method fit and transform our varriables to a polynomal model (of our choice of degree).
   For instance:

```
from sklearn.preprocessing import PolynomialFeatures

poly=PolynomialFeatures(degree=2)

poly.fit_transform(df[[firstColumn,secondColumn]],df[targetColumn])
```

So, the outcome is a 2-dimensional polynomial with df[firstColumn] and df[secondColumn] as varriables.

2) In polynomial regression, why do we need to use fit_tranform? What is the logic behind it?
For instance,

```
Xpoly=poly.fit_transform(X)

lin=LinearRegression()

lin.fit(Xpoly,y)
```

Answer (score 1):

From [sklearn documentation](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.preprocessing.PolynomialFeatures.html):

> **sklearn.preprocessing.PolynomialFeatures** 
>   Generate a new feature
>   matrix consisting of all polynomial combinations of the features with
>   degree less than or equal to the specified degree. For example, if an
>   input sample is two dimensional and of the form [a, b], the degree-2
>   polynomial features are [1, a, b, a^2, ab, b^2].

So, this does exactly as you think.

> **fit_transform(self, X, y=None, **fit_params)**
>  Fits transformer to X and
>   y with optional parameters fit_params and returns a transformed
>   version of X.

In sklearn, `fit()` just calculates the parameters and saves them as an internal objects state. Afterwards, you can call its `transform()` method to apply the transformation to a particular set of examples.

`fit_transform()` joins these two steps and is used for the initial fitting of parameters on the training set x, but it also returns a transformed x′. Internally, it just calls first `fit()` and then `transform()` on the same data.